# connect different programming lanquages

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

How can connect two different programming languages? for example i have developed an application which has been written by C# also i have another application which has been written by C++ i wanna know how can i connect them?

should i do this in a same project in visual studio or do something else?

how can make an application which has been combined with different languages? how can combine different programming languages?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define what you mean by `connect`?

Comment: You can mix projects in a solution but you CANNOT mix languages in the same project (normally).

Comment: We need more information on what you actually want to achieve here. "Connect" and "Combine" are just too vague.

Comment: I'm guessing they mean they have classes & methods in one language that they want to use in another.

Comment: @Lloyd so what should i do for mixing different languages?

Comment: @ChrisF mixing different languages

Comment: @aliboy38 "mixing" is still too vague. What do you **actually** want to do? Display a dialog defined in C++ from C#?

Comment: @ChrisF a single program which uses different programming languages

Comment: @aliboy38 You can have an exe written in one language that calls a dll written in another. You may also be able to embed the dll into the exe, but it will still have to be built separately.

Comment: I should point out you can mix with C++/CLI and have a mixed mode assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the two programs to communicate with each other? There are many ways to do that. The most common are probably sockets, named pipes and shared memory.

Named pipes and shared memory only works if the two programs runs on the same local machine, while sockets can of course be used over a network. If the have to communicate over a network, you can also look into e.g. message queues like [RabbitMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbitmq) or similar.

**Edit:** Reading your comments, it seems that you don't really want two separate programs, but a single program which uses different programming languages.

In that case you should probably make the C++ code as a DLL, and then load it into the C# program using e.g. [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).

Comment: yes. i wanna develop an application which has been written with different programming languages

Comment: @aliboy38 Updated my answer, because it seems like my first version wasn't about what you mean.